# CSS selector height 100% and width:auto, first failing and then working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I am looking for a workaround for a case where the `width:auto` CSS rule initially fails to apply, in Chrome, Safari and Opera. (There is no problem in the latest version of Firefox. Tested only on Mac so far.)

First I will describe the symptoms, then I will describe the issue.

**The symptoms**

In a web page, I want an image to fill the window completely. When the visitor resizes the window, the image will maintain its proportions and expand or contract to fill either the full height or the full width.

If you open [this page](http://dev.lexogram.com/tests/resize/) in your browser, and then resize the window, you should see that the grey border of the image is always visible either at the sides of the window or at the top and bottom. The image has a width:height ratio of 2:1.

The problem occurs if you load the page when your browser window has a width:height ratio of 2:1 or taller. To test, you can make the window square  (1:1) and then reload the page. If you make the window taller, all works correctly, but if you make the window shorter, then the image becomes deformed: it turns into an oval. If you continue to make the window shorter,  until its ration is 2:1 or wider, the problem disappears.

Making the window wider than 2:1 before making it shorter does not solve the problem.

**The issue**

The basic principle is to use the CSS below, plus JavaScript that runs on `window.onresize` to  toggle the class for the image depending on the ratio of the window's width and height compared to the image.

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

img.full-height {
height:100%;
width:auto;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
 /* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

img.full-width {
height:auto;
width:100%;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

This works fine in all browsers where I have tested it. However, in my case, I want to include a signature for the image in the bottom right corner of the window, and I also want to have this signature in the same parent `' as the full-size image.

Because the CSS above uses `transform` on the parent `<div>`, it is not possible to use `position: fixed` for any of the children of the parent `<div>`. The body of the HTML and the CSS that I use are shown below.

I would be grateful to anyone who can help me find a workaround that cures the symptoms in all browsers.

*Body*

```
<div class="shrinkwrap">;
  <div class="shrinkwrap full-width">
    <img src="circle.png" alt />
  </div>
  <p class="signature">Signature</p>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

div.shrinkwrap {
display:inline-block;
position: fixed;
}

div.full-height,
div.full-height img{
height:100%;
width:auto;
}

div.full-height img{
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

div.full-height{
left: 50%;
}

div.full-width {
height:auto;
width:100%;
top: 50%;

-webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

div.full-width img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

p.signature {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very problematic and prone to breaking if you need to require the user to keep a 2:1 ratio.

Have you tried using the background-size  properties instead?

`background-size: cover;`

Will scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.

`background-size: contain;`

Will scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area.

Example:

```css
div{
  color:white;
  margin:10px;
}

.cover {
    background:red;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/PnD8bZ9.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

.contain {
    background:yellow;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/PnD8bZ9.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">cover 500x500 div</div>

<div class="contain">contain 500x500 div</div>
```